# PHP / OCI Invalid Character during insert

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I am trying to do an Oracle insert statement on a PHP page but I am getting the error below. If I remove the semicolon from the statement, the page never loads (even though the insert on the backend should take a fraction of a second). Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
$sql_update = "
update schema.table set last_check_dt = (select sysdate from dual)
where id = (select id from schema.email where current_email = '" . $email . "');";

$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql_update);
oci_execute($stid); 
oci_commit($conn);
oci_close($conn);

Warning: oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

Comment: 3 things to check: the semicolon is not useful but should not be a problem, the subquery in your set element is weird, is that the problem ? Also your last subquery would be better with "id IN (SELECT...."

Comment: @nek subquery issue, I agree what you say,but would end up with a different error, not invalid character..

Comment: The semicolon look like a wrong character here, that's the best interpretation for the error. The ( after the = is more like "parsing error after token =".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql_update = "
update schema.table set last_check_dt = (select sysdate from dual)
where id = (select id from schema.email where current_email = '" . $email . "')";
```

Your SQL, when run through a `OCI`.. Don't need a `semicolon` as terminator.

Comment: Thank you - but for some reason with that SQL the page will no longer load. It clocks but nothing happens.

Comment: You have any locks over the table? It might wait indefinitely till the lock is released.

Comment: WOW! it happened to be a lock, I really doubted it but there was another window open running an un-commited query... this drove me nuts. THANK YOU